# No results found on kibana -> discover

Tags: kibana

[image]we followed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/advanced-pipeline.html to configure apache logs on kibana, everything looked fine until we clicked discover on Kibana: No results found, we did create index patterns as attached...any advice would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: curl -XGET '192.168.112.199:9200/logstash-2017.08.21/_search?pretty&q=response=200' , this command works fine, there are ip, country, geo information...,

Comment: When you create the index-pattern, which date field did you choose?

Comment: did you mean daily ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXUUI3R0t4LVZ6R2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I mean @timestamp.please do search request and look at the value of timestamp field in the first document, does the date is valid?

Comment: sorry , I am new to kinana and I don't get it ? click on discover and search some keywords? which steps of this document(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/advanced-pipeline.html) , thanks

Comment: Look at my answer, the problem is easy that I thought

Comment: This is what I have done, could you specify which steps?  sorry for my first time using Kibana....management -> create index pattern-> check on "use event times..."->
filter field name "@timestamp"-> index pattern interval"Daily"->create

Comment: Like I said, the problem is diffrent that I thought before, look at my answer I added image also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152557/discussion-between-joe-yang-and-lax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]In the discover page, in the right top corner you have time range, the default is 15 minutes, choose instead 5 years or even more.

Comment: yes, thanks a ton, after applying your advice,  I can see some data in discover now , btw, my dashboard is something wrong, there's only one bar as attached, Do I have to open another new question for dashboard? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YdUMoS4l7uQnhPY3dtRkZ1dFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think it will better if you will open new question

Comment: appreciate your prompt advice, will open a new one, hopefully, you can can pick it up once you get a chance, you did solve my issue in one minute ^^"

Comment: btw, there's only one bar on the last page of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/advanced-pipeline.html, so my discover looks as fine as the above ?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YdUMoS4l7uRTQwVHFxTmNtRzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its totaly OK , youre time range is between 2017-07-09 to 2017-08-20 if you will decrase the range, you will see more bars

Comment: I just decreased the range, there's only one as usual: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YdUMoS4l7uRTQwVHFxTmNtRzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume that all of your data is in the same day

Comment: I will look at in the next 3 hours, mean while I offer you to delete the comment with your URL, someone can doing harmful things to your index

Comment: or could you give me a sample apache sample log which I can show several bars ?

Comment: What is your email? Stack overflow don't like a lot of comment

Comment: joeyangx@yahoo.com